# AssertFailedException in CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent (Both lists are filled with same content)

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I get following AssertFailedException and can't see, why this happens.

> CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent failed. The expected collection
>   contains 1 occurrence(s) of <FileExporter.Document>. The actual
>   collection contains 0 occurrence(s).

Code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetDocumentsTest()
{
    List<Document> testDocuments = new List<Document>() {
      new Document(){ Path = "TestDoc1", Language = "DEU" }
    , new Document(){ Path = "TestDoc2", Language = "ENG" }
    };

    string sqlCommand = "SELECT Path, LanguageCode FROM Document WITH(NOLOCK) ORDER BY Id";
    string connectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\Documents.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
    List<Document> documents = new DataAccessManagerTestMockup().GetDocuments(sqlCommand, connectionString);
// Sql gets same documents with same path and same language

    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(testDocuments, documents);
}
```

Update:

```
namespace FileExporter
{
    public class Document
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string Language { get; set; }

        public bool Equals(Document y)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, y))
                return true;
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;
            return this.Path == y.Path && this.Language == y.Language;
        }
    }
}
```

Update 2:

I think i shouldn't spend a night in cologne (3 hours driving time) and try to code.
Colleague just said me i should override equals and use an object instead of Document.

```
namespace FileExporter
{
    public class Document
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string Language { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object y)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, y))
                return true;
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(this, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;
            return this.Path == ((Document) y).Path && this.Language == ((Document) y).Language;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
        if (this == null)
            return 0;
        int hashCodePath = this.Path == null ? 0 : this.Path.GetHashCode();
        int hashCodeLanguage = this.Language == null ? 0 : this.Language.GetHashCode();

        return hashCodePath ^ hashCodeLanguage;

        }
}
```

Comment: Can you debug this and check if "documents" has any items?

Comment: Yes, it got 2 items (same properties in exact same order as "testDocuments")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to succeed your Document class needs to implement (override) `Equals()`

You can verify this easily:

```
var d1 = new Document(){ Path = "TestDoc1", Language = "DEU" };
var d2 = new Document(){ Path = "TestDoc1", Language = "DEU" };

Assert.AreEqual(d1, d2);
```

Comment: Strange behavior. Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<FileExporter.Document>. Actual:<FileExporter.Document>. I added iEqualityComparer<Document> yestarday (.Equals()) still implemented.

Comment: That's default behaviour (return of type-name). Override ToString() to get a better message. It does show where your problem is. But be careful about implementing Equals.

Comment: If i return Path and Language in .ToString() they are equal. Assert.AreEqual(d1.ToString(), d2.ToString());

Comment: Yes, but CollectionAssert depends on `Assert.IsTrue(d1.Equals(d2))`

Comment: Just be careful, Your object has other risks now. Like GetHashCode() and Equals() disagreeing.

Comment: TY Henk. I have a look at that, I added GetHashCode to it. I will update on my question.